# How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{1+\tan^{2019}x}dx$

Tags: integration

How to integrate $$\int^{2018} _{0} \frac{1}{1+\tan^{2019}x}dx$$

I came across this question early this morning. 
I tried substituting $t=\tan x$. But nothing really came to be easy.

Is there an antiderivative ? or not ?

Comment: Notice that this is an improper integral and the first question is whether it even converges.

Comment: Is it an olympiad or contest problem?

Comment: There is no antiderivative.  Are you sure that the upper limit isn't a multiple of $\pi/2$ (e.g., $2018\pi$)?

Comment: @MarkViola Im not sure . But if it was $\pi/2$ or something like that , can I use $f(x) , f(a-x)$ method ?

Comment: Yes, in that case the substitution $x\mapsto \pi/2-x$ works.

Comment: Idea to be worked out... By substitution $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+\tan^{2019} x} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{du}{(1+u^2)(1+u^{2019})}$ and then residue theorem or partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net. Why not just make the substitution $x\mapsto \pi/2-x$ and find immediately that the answer is $\pi/4$.  And here, partial fraction expansion is intractable practically speaking.

Comment: @MarkViola I’m probably missing something... I don’t understand why the substitution $x\mapsto \pi/2-x$ allows to say that the value of the integral is $\pi/4$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{1+\tan^a(x)}\,dx&\overbrace{=}^{x\mapsto\pi/2-x}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^a(\pi/2-x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\cot^a(\pi/2-x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan^a(x)}{1+\tan^a(x)}\,dx\\\\
&\pi/2-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^a(x)}\,dx
\end{align}$$Can you see the light? ;-))

Comment: @MarkViola Indeed simple... Just need to write!

Comment: A rational function of trigs has an elementary antiderivative. But your integrand has simple poles at $x = 3 \pi/4 + \pi k$. Are you considering the principal value integral?